# DatabaseMetaData program not fetching table names

Tags: java, oracle, database-metadata

I have created a program to fetch all the table names from the user rt using `DatabaseMetaData`, although the program is compiled successfully and running it is not fetching the table names. It runs and displays list of tables: and then no names. Program exits.

Could anyone here please help me to find the wrong logic in my program.

```
//DataBaseMetaDataTest
import java.sql.*;
class DatabaseMetaDataTest
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        try
        {
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","rt","pwdd");
            DatabaseMetaData dbmd=con.getMetaData();
            ResultSet rs=dbmd.getTables(null,"rt",null,new String[]{"Table"});
            System.out.println("list of tables:");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you can get the metadata only from the specified table with the DatabaseMetaData( http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.sql/ResultSetgetMetaData.htm)

Comment: why dont you use the all_tables system table ("dictionary")?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle schema (=user) names are stored in upper case, so you also need to pass the schema name in upper case in the JDBC call.

I think you also need to pass the type list in upper case as well.

```
dbmd.getTables(null,"RT",null,new String[]{"TABLE"});
```

Comment: help me with another program...please